# Craft CP and a11y

Tags: control-panel

Is there some documentation/summary to which degree Craft's CP supports accessibility (a11y), WCAG2 compliance?

Especially support for color blindness and keyboard only usage is requested in an upcoming project, screen reader support preferred, but optional.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no documentation I'm aware of (official or unofficial), but there is a Github issue here to improve some aspects of a11y you might want to comment and ask for clarification on: https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues/1533